# Regex search and replacement in a long string

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have a long string which represents CSS applied to a page;

`const string = '.blog{background-color:#eff0f1;border color:#eff0f1} .header{background:rgba(33,37,41,0.125);}'`;

I am trying to replace `rgba(33,37,41,0.125)` in the string with appropriate hexcode.

My regex looks like this:

`let rgbRegex = /^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?\)$/g;`

When I am trying to replace occurrences of rgba code in the CSS string it does not do anything.

`let anotherString = string.replace(regex, '#123123');`   //does not work

However, if I try to match directly with 'rgba(33,37,41,0.125)' it works.

`let anotherString = string.replace('rgba(33,37,41,0.125)', '#123123');`  //works

My regex is correct, can anyone tell what else could be the issue ?

Comment: The problem is that you used `^...$`. That's why 'rgba(33,37,41,0.125)' match

Comment: So what regex can be used instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cuong points out in the comment, you used `^...$` which mean "the start of the string" and "the end of the string". 
If you remove those signs you should be able to match the `rgba` part, so this should work: 
`let rgbRegex = /rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?\)/g;`

Check this out: https://regex101.com/r/brO25z/1

Answer (score 2):

Your regex will never match because you anchor the string at the beginning and end, but you want to match a pattern within the string.

You can use this regex:

```js
const str = '.blog{background-color:#eff0f1;border color:#eff0f1} .header{background:rgba(33,37,41,0.125);}';
const regex = /\brgba?\(([^\)]*)\)/g;
let result = str.replace(regex, '#123123');
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
.blog{background-color:#eff0f1;border color:#eff0f1} .header{background:#123123;}
```

Explanation:

- `\brgba?` - match `rgb` or `rgba` using word boundary `\b`
- `\(` - literal `(`
- `([^\)]*)` - capture group with everything up to and just before the next `)`
- `\)` - literal `)`

A benefit to using `/\brgba?\(([^\)]*)\)/g` is that it is computationally simple to match. The RegEx is processed in one direction and doesn't have multiple capture groups.

#### Super-charged replacement

[`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) also supports using a function as the second parameter, this allows you to transform whatever the RegEx matches dynamically using the [arguments passed to the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). The functions's first argument is the matched substring (which we don't need), but the second argument will contain the capture group we specified for everything inside the parentheses of `rgb()` and `rgba()`.

```js
const str = '.blog{background-color:#eff0f1;border color:#eff0f1} .header{background:rgba(33,37,41,0.125);}';
const regex = /\brgba?\(([^\)]*)\)/g;
let result = str.replace(regex, (match, g1) => {
  const [r,g,b,a] = g1.split(/\s*,\s*/);
  const parts = (a !== undefined ? [Math.floor(a * 255), r, g, b] : [r, g, b]);
  return parts.reduce((hexStr, comp) => hexStr + `0${Number(comp).toString(16)}`.slice(-2), "#");
});
console.log(result);
```

Explanation:

- `const [r,g,b,a] = g1.split(/\s*,\s*/)` - take the first capture group (the inside of the parentheses from our match), split it into parts separated by a comma, and use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to save each respective part as `r`, `g`, `b`, and `a`.
- The format of a basic hexadecimal color is `#RRGGBB`, whereas a hexadecimal color with an alpha value is `#AARRGGBB`
- `Math.floor(a * 255)` - because `a` is a value between `0.0` and `1.0`, we need to convert it to an integer in the range `0` to `255`.
- `const parts = (a !== undefined ? [Math.floor(a * 255), r, g, b] : [r, g, b]);` - When you match a string without an alpha value (like `rgb(33,37,41)`), `a` will be `undefined`. Here we create an array with the components in the right order, omitting `a` when it's not needed.
- `Number(comp).toString(16)` - this takes the variable `comp`, converts it to a number and then back to a string, but this time in hexadecimal notation.
- `("0" + Number(comp).toString(16)).slice(-2)` - this takes the result of the hexadecimal conversion, places a `"0"` in front of it and then takes the last two characters of that string. So `Number("16").toString(16)` (which is `"f"`) will become `"0f"` and `Number("17").toString(16)` (which is `"10"`) will still be `"10"`.
- `return parts.reduce((hexStr, comp) => hexStr + COMP_AS_HEX, "#");` - Convert each component in `parts` to hex, flatten it to `#AARRGGBB` or `#RRGGBB` and return the value (replacing the original match).

Comment: @rach8garg As you are looking to replace with the appropriate hexadecimal codes, I'd take another look at this answer with the new edits.

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman, nice addition with code execution in replace!